# External hard drive connected to amazon basics usb hub doesn't appear - Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, hard-drive, 20.04, 19.10

Today I uploaded ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04. If I connect my hard drive directly to usb port, it works, instead if I connect it to amazon basics usb hub, it doesn't appear.

How can i fix it?

---

EDIT: I have a second external hard drive; also this doesn't work if I connect it to the amazon basics usb hub. Instead the printer works.

Comment: If the usb hub is a 2.0 or low power 3 then it doesn't have enough power to reliably spin and talk to the external drive.

Comment: @walttheboss the USB hub is 3.0 and has a power supply (it worked on Ubuntu 19.10)

Comment: OK here is a test.  Run a live usb/dvd of 20.04.  See if it works that way.  If it does then 20.04 is not the issue.  Sometimes if you run an upgrade things get blocked in the process.  That means your new install may have blacklisted the drive.